# I cannot print in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++

I'm working with visual studio 2015, and I have a problem, when I debug my console application doesn't show nothing, I have tried lots things but it doesn't work, I think that it could be a problem of my pc, but I don't know what could it be.
[image]

Comment: Try to disable your antivirus

Comment: Hello, tanks, that was the problem, i have avast, you know how can I disable the antivirus only for the program?

Comment: I don't now what antivirus you use and that's also off-topic for SO.